# What is the the Laplace transform of $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}(-1)^nu(t-n)$?

Tags: laplace-transform

What is the the Laplace transform of $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}(-1)^nu(t-n)$?

u(t-n) is a step function.
$$
u(t-n) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            0 & \quad x < n \\
            1 & \quad x \geq n
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

My professor gives this question on a homework. I am baffled by how to deal with the varying $n$ in the step function and the changing sign. Can I turn this into an integral?

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
\mathcal L \{f(t)\}& = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_0^\infty (-1)^n e^{-st} u(t-n) \\
& = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n e^{-ns}}{s} = \frac{1}{s}\frac{1}{1+e^{-s}}
\end{align}

Comment: can you explain how you obtain the close form for the sum in the last step?

Comment: See Jose Garcia's comment in his answer.

Comment: Oh yeah, its a geomtric sum. Each successive term is being multiplied by $-e^{-s}$.

Answer (score 0):

i think there is no closed form, the Laplace tranfsorm of the step function given by $ u(t-n)$ is equal to

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty}dt u(t-n)exp(-st) =\frac{e^{-sn}}{s} $$

Comment: Yeah, i know that integral. But what does it have to do with the summation?

Comment: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}e^{-sn}= \frac{1}{1+e^{-s}} $